# Get result object as undifine when getting data from web api. only in first call

Tags: angular, get

Trying to get array of data from web Api. When I call first time api the result return indicate undefined. Any call after that getting result as expected.

Oncall method store result to stations

```
@Injectable()
export class StationService {

    private stations;
    constructor(private webservice: WebService) { }

    Oncall() {
        this.webservice.GetData('Search/GetStations').subscribe((respons: Station[]) => { this.stations = respons; });
        console.log(this.stations);
        console.log('----------------------------------');
    }
}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Station } from '../dataModels/stationModel';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class WebService {
    private url = 'http://localhost:11835/Api/';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    GetData(path: string) {
        return this.http.get<Station[]>((this.url + path)).pipe(
            map((data: Station[]) => data)
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in your code:

```
    Oncall() {
        this.webservice.GetData('Search/GetStations').subscribe((respons: Station[]) => { 
         this.stations = respons;
         console.log(this.stations);
         console.log('----------------------------------');
        });

    }
```

The problem is that the first time you call the service function (GetData) it takes a while to get the data and you are running console.log (this.stations); after. That part of your code runs asynchronously and does not wait for the assignment to be done this.stations = respons;

The next time it is called then it shows the previous values

Answer (score 0):

Your console log is outside of the scope of the assignment. Before the data has a chance to come back, you're trying to log the object which you see if undefined. When you hit it the second time, the data has been retrieved from the first call, that's why it's logging, but you'll probably notice that the data is stale if you've made any changes to it.

If you want to see the console.log after you initially get the data, add the console log to where the data is being assigned to the object like so.

```
Oncall() {
        this.webservice.GetData('Search/GetStations').subscribe((respons: Station[]) => { 
         this.stations = respons;
         console.log(this.stations);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your console.log code is occurring synchronously, since you have it outside the scope of your subscribe function, so it is returning undefined. However, immediately after that, the asynchronous code resolves and sets 'this.stations' to the response. So, you are always viewing the result one web request behind.

The changes Leonardo suggested will cause the log to occur after the http request has resolved